# observed information matrix for logistic model

Tags: r

I have proposed my own model and now am trying to implement it using R, I have got stuck on how to find the observed matrix applying my formula i have use glm() to fit logistic model with penalty term, using binary data set x1, x2, x3 ,y (all binary 0,1) fit1 if the glm() model def.new is the penalise deviance.

```
X.tilde <- as.matrix(x)                                     # n*p matrix of the data set 
W <- Diagonal(length(y), weights)                           # n*n diagonal matrix of the weights
qq <- exp(fit1$fitted.values)/(1 + exp(fit1$fitted.values)) # n*1 vector (pi=probability of the logistic model )
cc <- t(1 - qq)                                             # n*1 vector 
gg <- (dev.new) * t(dev.new)                                # p*p matrix
ff <- (X.tilde) %*% t(X.tilde)                              # n*n matrix
pp <- exp(fit1$coefficients)/(1 + exp(fit1$coefficients))   # p*1 matrix
ss <- t(1/(1 + exp(fit1$coefficients)))                     # p*1 vector
aa <- t(X.tilde) %*% qq %*% cc %*% W %*% (X.tilde)          # p*p matrix
firstP <- (aa + (pp * ss))                                  # p*p matrix
info.mat <- firstP+gg                                       # p*p matrix
info.mat <- as.matrix(info.mat)
```

this code returns the following error

> Error in e1 + Matrix(e2) :
> Matrices must have same number of rows for arithmetic

As in my theory the dimension is fine by when I implement its not correct
any help?

r

Comment: Can you update your question please in regards to the comments at your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442193/calculation-of-observed-information-matrix-for-logistic-model-with-penalised-log) question -- we still can't answer this without the additional details. Thanks

Comment: ... just from looking at the dimensions that you give; if a vector is nx1 (qq for example) then its transpose will not be nx1 ... so we really need a reproducible example